# How to set minimum and target .NET framework for VB.NET in VS2013

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm facing the following problems that I don't understand:

1. How do I set the minimum and target .NET framework?
2. How does it work or what stand for target .NET Framework?
3. And is there a way to set the .NET Framework which works with any Windows OS version?

Comment: Check the **My Project --> Target Framework Property** and check [ask]

Comment: Sorry! 
i don't understand you and please check my question again.

Comment: Sorry please learn how to ask a question: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I set the minimum and target .NET framework?

Answer: [How to: Change the Target .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx)

> How does it work or what stand for target .NET Framework?

Answer:

The frameworks are designed to be backwards-compatible; if you have a program written in .NET 2.0, you can run it in the 4.0 runtime, because none of the frameworks ever remove functionality that a prior version had (which is why we still have the non-generic collections like ArrayList, even though they're deprecated in favor of generic collections). However, the reverse is not necessarily true; a 4.0 app is not guaranteed to run in 2.0, because it MAY take advantage of new features of the new runtime that are not available in prior versions. In any case, if you want your app to attempt to run on runtime versions it does not specifically target, you must specify that in the app.config using SupportedRuntime elements.

> And is there a way to set the .NET Framework which works with any Windows OS version?

Answer: [How to: Configure an App to Support .NET Framework 4 or 4.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Version Compatibility in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939(v=vs.110).aspx)